# Calendar From Multiple Content Types

Tags: views, nodes, datetime

I have a 4 seperate calendars created on drupal; each with their own content type. Each of these need to be able to be viewed on their own but I'd also like to be able to combine all of these calendars into one master view and can't seem to figure it out.

ie. Meetings calendar, Holidays calendar, Staff Events calendar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to Drupal so please be gentle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the calendar views setup already, there's a few ways to show them all together

1. Views attachment displays ( maybe )
2. [views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) in a template ( ok, if comfortable with PHP )
3. [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) ( recommended )

For example, using Panels, you can create a page with a particular layout and simply embed the View displays into the Panel page via the user interface.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear. I want to have all the different events showing up in one calendar view; not just on one page.

Answer (score 0):

all content types MUST use same date field, then make 5 calenadar views, 1-4 on filter cryteria do choose only one content type, there you have a calendar view for each content type, on 5th view (your 'master' view) in filter cryteria do choose all 4 content types. Now in a single calendar view you will have all 4 content types mixed toghether. Example filtering by content type:

[image]